# Time in Java: I don't want to see seconds

Tags: java, time

I have a class called `Lezione` that has an attribute `time` of type `Time`. This attributes is filled with the value of the attribute time of the table Lezione in my database (mysql). Also, the attribute time in the database is of type `TIME`.

Now: I do a query on the db:

```
 select * from lezione as l
```

and then I create an object of type Lezione and I set all the attributes. For the time I do this:

```
l.settime(rs2.getTime(3));
```

And this Works.

When I try to print the value with l.gettime() I get the value (f.e.) `13:00:00`

What I would like to have instead is `13:00`

I tried with the expression

```
l.gettime().getHours()+":"+l.gettime().getMinutes()
```

(that uses *depreciated* methods) but it prints `13:0` (and I guess that if I would like to print `09:02` it would print `9:2`)

So What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simpledate formatter.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
formatter.format( time ) ); // 13:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also go with `DateFormat`.

But you can add leading zeros with

```
String.format("%02d", yournumber);
```

So in your case it would like:

```
l.gettime().getHours()+":"+String.format("%02d", l.gettime().getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

To format a Date/Time you should use a (Simple)DateFormat, for example:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

This prints the current time in 24-hour format (HH) with seconds. To not print seconds, just change the format to "HH:mm".

Comment: I thought I leave something to the reader's imagination. Also, DateFormatter is an equally viable answer as opposed to DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat for that matter. Who knows what kind of application he/she is developing, could be a Java Swing app, who knows?

Comment: A DateFormatter uses a DateFormat. There's no point in usign a DateFormatter outside of a Swing program. And you need a DateFormat to use it anyway.

Comment: I know, I know, I made a typo... So much for trying to talk you out of downvoting my answer ;)

Comment: You'd better *fix* your answer if you want me to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in printing the string from `getTime`, then you could do like this:

```
String str = rs2.getTime(3);
str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 3);
System.out.println(str);
```

Although, that might be a little ugly.

Comment: You probably mean `.length()`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this as you can see in the answers. Here is another way to display hours and minutes (and other details from `Calendar`):

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
int  minutes = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int  hours = date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //HOUR_OF_DAY for the 24-hour clock
System.out.println("The time is: "+ hours+ ":" +minutes);
```